# I wrote this code in bash shell script with error

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu

I wrote this code:

```
echo -n "Enter a number1  "
echo -n "Enter a number2  "
read R1
read R2

while [ "$R1" < "$R2"]
do 
if [ $((R1 % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then

$R3=$R1

    echo "Number is $R3"
else
    echo "Nothing"
fi

done
```

I don't understand why it always give me this error bash: 8]: No such file or directory

Comment: Your specific error message is caused by the lack of space before the closing `]` argument, which would need to be inserted in addition to the fix given in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-lt` instead of `<`.

```
while [ "$R1" -lt "$R2" ]
```

`<` is interpreted as input redirection in bash.

Or you can use double square brackets to interpret those inside as arithmetic operation:

```
while [[ "$R1" < "$R2" ]]
```

Comment: thank you it works but I stuck with infinite loop that disappointed me 
command not found;number =2;

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Asking user to input two number everytime?

Comment: am thinking of Write a Bash shell script that reads as arguments two integer parameters (R1, and R2), if R1 < R2, prints all even numbers between R1 and R2. Otherwise prints out nothing, so I do this

Comment: @justhalf I think, you gave the answer first with correct fix+1 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What happens since `< "$R2"` is intrepreted as *read from* `"$R2"`. Since you don't have a file with such a name, it complains.

`[` (test command) command doesn't have `<` operator. You have to use `-lt` instead:

```
while [ "$R1" -lt "$R2" ]
```

There's a POSIX extenstion which supports it with a slash:

```
while [ "$R1" \< "$R2" ]
```

---

If you are using bash you bash then you can also use built-in `[[ ..]]` which has support for `<`, `>` etc.

```
while [[ "$R1" < "$R2" ]]
```

See also:

[**What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

---

After re-writing your code to put the loop *inside* `if`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a number1  "
read R1
echo -n "Enter a number2  "
read R2

if [[ "$R1" < "$R2" ]]
then
  for((i=R1;i<R2;i++));
  do
    if [[ $((i % 2)) -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo "Number is $i"
    fi
  done
else
    echo "Nothing"
fi
```

Comment: thank you it works but I stuck with infinite loop that disappointed me      command not found;number =2

Comment: You don't change neither of `R1` and `R2`. Hence, once it enters the loop, it won't break. Depending on what you wanted to do with the code, you may change `R1` or `R2` or use a `break` statement on some condition.

Comment: am thinking of Write a Bash shell script that reads as arguments two integer parameters (R1, and R2), if R1 < R2, prints all even
numbers between R1 and R2. Otherwise prints out nothing, so I do this

Comment: I'll give the honor to you Blue Moon, to solve this problem, rather than competing each other. =)

Comment: should I make R1,R2 initially equal o zero

Comment: @HaneenAbd-Al-Haleem I have re-written your code and updated the answer. Basically you should put the loop inside the condition. You can also do the same using `while` loop if you prefer.

Comment: thaaaank you am just new on shell script I like it now =)